# Complete question timeline including votes

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, timeline

Is there any chance to get more information in questions timeline such as when it has been upvoted, when it has been downvoted, same for all answers, including comments, and other actions such as vote for close and so on?

Answer (score 2):

Voting data will never be exposed (as a stream anyway) with great accuracy, as its too easy to correlate it with user activity*.

Easier streaming of site updates (questions, answers, comments, edits, etc.) is something I'm considering for the next version, though.

<sub>*Provided some minimum amount of traffic to the site, anonymity is more or less guarantee-able if we scrub voting data.</sub>

Comment: Good point. I think that what I want to build must be server-side for that exact reason.